# Pressure drop through a flat vs. pleated filter

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Consider two identical pipes where two identical air flows take place. The pipes are "obstructed" by two filters made of the same fabric, one flat, the other pleated as shown in the following picture.

[image]

### Qualitatively

In which pipe will the pressure drop be larger? I see two opposing factors:

- The folded filter has more "holes" overall, so its hydrodynamic resistance is lower.
- If you imagine the filter fabric to be made of small channels normal to its surface, air undergoes more shear to cross the pleated filter than to cross the flat one.

Mechanical ventilation systems commonly use pleated filters for fine fabrics: is it only to increase their lifespan (larger area means it takes longer to seal them up), or does it also reduce pressure drop?

### Quantitatively

What section should a flat filter have to yield the same pressure drop as a pleated filter? This question boils down to: Are there formulas or charts to compute the pressure drop as a function of dimensions $a$ and $t$?

Comment: I think it's pretty simple and just what you guessed - the total area of the filter material. Pleating is just a way to get more surface area in a given volume.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a bit wary of "simple" stuff in hydrodynamics, hence my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a first approximation, and if you have a laminar flow in the pipes, the flux will be $Q=\frac{-\kappa A}{\mu} \frac{(p_b - p_a)}{L}$, from [Darcy's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_flow_through_porous_media), see notations there. So increasing the area $A$ will increase the flux in proportion. Conversely, as you can see from the equation, the pressure drop is inversely proportional to $A$, if you impose flux. You can easily calculate $A$ from $a$ and $t$.